# evaluation of this logarithmic integrals

Tags: integration

what is the value $$ \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\log^{n}(x)}{x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x $$

'a' is a positive integer and so is 'n'

my gues with a change of variable $ x=e^{t} $ is that this integral would be related to the incomplete gamma function $$ \Gamma (n.\log(a)) $$

Comment: @Julián Aguirre. I am living next to you ! Un abrazo.

Comment: I am living next to you too ! Un abrazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica gave:

$$\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\log^{n}(x)}{x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma(n+1,\log(a))$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Integrate by parts using $u=\log^n(x)$, $dv=\frac{dx}{x^2}$. You will arrive to a splendid recurrence relation.

I am sure that you can take from here.